# Correspondence between the set of total orderings of a finite set $E$ and the symmetric group of $E$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, order-theory

Given a finite set $E$, does there exist a canonical one-to-one correspondence between the set of total orderings of $E$ and $\mathfrak{S}_{E}$ (the symmetric group of $E$)?

Comment: I'd say there's a canonical regular action of the symmetric group on the set of total orderings.

Comment: Do you happen to know a source that discusses the construction of this action?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Let $<$ be a total order on $E$, eg if $E = \{x_1, \dots,x_n\}$, set $x_i<x_j :\Leftrightarrow i < j$.

A permutation $\sigma$ induces a total ordering $<_\sigma$ as follows :
$$ x <_\sigma y :\Longleftrightarrow \sigma^{-1}(x) < \sigma^{-1}(y)$$

And the correspondence $\varphi : \sigma \mapsto <_\sigma$ is a one to one correspondence between the permutations of $E$ and the total orderings on $E$ :

*$\varphi$ is invertible:*
Let $\prec$ be a total order on $E$. We build a permutation $\sigma =\varphi^{-1}(\prec)$ by induction :

- One sets $\sigma(1) := \min_\prec (E)$.
- Let $1<n<|E|$, if $\sigma(1),\dots,\sigma(n)$ were constructed, we set $\sigma(n+1) := \min_\prec E\setminus \{\sigma(1),\dots,\sigma(n)\}$

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $E$ is already totally ordered. Thus you are doing what Lord Shark mentioned in his comment, which is a constructing a canonical action of the symmetric group on the set of all total ordering.

Comment: Yes indeed the order $<$ on $E$ isn't canonical.